# SQLAlchemy - how to add a constant

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a fairly complicated query that has been trimmed down for this article.   I am trying to run it on PostgreSQL using sqlalchemy.

```
q = sc.query(source_table.serial_no,
             source_table.start_time,
             func.extract('isodow',source_table.start_time)+func.literal_column('1', Numeric)).filter_by(serial_no=serial_number)
```

At the moment, I want to get the weekday and then add a constant value to it, but I keep getting output like this when I print it to screen using print(q):

```
SELECT power_data_1day.serial_no AS power_data_1day_serial_no, power_data_1day.start_time AS power_data_1day_start_time, -EXTRACT(isodow FROM power_data_1day.start_time) + literal_column(%(literal_column_1)s, %(literal_column_2)s) AS anon_1 
FROM power_data_1day 
WHERE power_data_1day.serial_no = %(serial_no_1)s
```

I have tried a number of different things including just adding 1, but I keep getting the parameter %(....) in the query.

How do I add a constant to a column in SQLAlchemy ?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Having a parameter in the generated query is not a problem *per se*. This code adds the constant value as expected:

```py
mytable = sa.Table(
    "mytable",
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    sa.Column("start_time", sa.DateTime),
)

mytable.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
mytable.create(engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    d = datetime(2021, 8, 6, 8, 0, 0)  # a Friday, isodow = 5
    conn.execute(sa.insert(mytable), {"id": 1, "start_time": d})

    q = sa.select(
        mytable.c.id, sa.func.extract("isodow", mytable.c.start_time) + 3
    )
    results = conn.execute(q).fetchall()
    """SQL generated:
    2021-08-06 13:52:35,846 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT mytable.id, EXTRACT(isodow FROM mytable.start_time) + %(param_1)s AS anon_1 
    FROM mytable
    2021-08-06 13:52:35,846 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00040s] {'param_1': 3}
    """
    print(results)
    # [(1, 8.0)]
```

However, if you want the resulting value to also be a valid isodow then you'll need to "wrap" it to be in the range [1..7]. In this case the resulting day is the following Monday, so it should be `1`, not `8`.